# C# .Net - Insert text in Bookmark without opening Word

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

I managed to insert a text in a Bookmark of a Word document using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.

```
        using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
        using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
        using Range = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range;

        Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\wordDocument.docx");
        string bookmark = "bookmarkName";

        Bookmark bm = doc.Bookmarks[bookmark];
        Range range = bm.Range;
        range.Text = "Hello World";
        doc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark, range);

        /* OR
            doc.Bookmarks[bookmark].Select();
            app.Selection.TypeText("Hello");
        */
```

The problem is this also opened the Word document. Can this be done without opening the document itself? Like its all happening in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `Save` and `Close` function after updating the text of the Bookmark of your Word Document.

Add the below code after the `doc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark, range);`.

```
doc.Save();
doc.Close();
```

**EDIT:**
If the computer is slow, the Word document might show within a second since you open it up. As [hardcoregamer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6670491/hardcoregamer) said, you can try to hide the object of `Word.Application` first before opening it.

```
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
    using Range = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range;

    Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    app.Visible = false; //Hide the Word.Application object.
    Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\wordDocument.docx");
    string bookmark = "bookmarkName";

    Bookmark bm = doc.Bookmarks[bookmark];
    Range range = bm.Range;
    range.Text = "Hello World";
    doc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark, range);
    doc.Save(); //save the document.
    doc.Close(); //close the document.
    app.Quit(); //close the Word.Application object. otherwise, you'll get a ReadOnly error later.
```

Comment: It does work and I don't see the document get opened. However, I have a fast computer, what if the computer is not that fast? Will it show the document and close it for a second?

Comment: @Bolomeo Try `Word.Application().Visible = false` before opening it.